# Using .scrollTo() to scroll to a section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use .scrollTo in jquery to scroll to another section based on if the scroll direction was up or down.
I have the scrollTo source code in the example but the scroll is still scrolling regularly.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b9ybuxy3/)

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      $('body').scrollTo('.one');
   } else {
      $('body'.scrollTo('.two');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: You are binding an event to `window`, but applying the result to `body`, that alone should tell you something is off. Specifically, some browsers use `document.body` as the scroll root, others use `document.documentElement`.

Comment: [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) takes coordinates. So you need to give it `0,$(".one").offset().top` instead of `(".one")`

Comment: for one, you need to close your selector for `$('body')` in your else statement

Comment: To scroll the screen to a matched target element:

$('body').scrollTo('#target');

from the plugins site

Comment: first, fix the typo in  `$('body'.scrollTo('.two');` **$("body" <----"**

Comment: you have a logical problem with your `$(window)scroll... ` when the function is called once, it calls the other one. here is the example calling only one of them https://jsfiddle.net/b9ybuxy3/1/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$("body").stop().animate({
    scrollTop : $(".one").offset().top
});
```

(offset may need to be changed to position depending on your site)

-edit: added .stop(), which will stop animation overlap

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o23moguo/ it seems to be calling the if/else statement multiple times on one scroll? It will scroll down, then up then down again on one scroll down.